# Geoprocessing return not showing on map?

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, geoprocessing-service, esri-leaflet

I have a geoprocessing service that works fine in ArcMap and ArcGIS online.

http://argis.ualr-iea.org/arcgis/rest/services/geoServices/SiteFinder/GPServer/FindSites.

I am trying to integrate it into an esri leaflet project. http://argis.ualr-iea.org/artrans/.

The service runs and returns data, but the results are not shown on the map, there are no errors and I don't recognize the Lat / Long returned?

To run this, I have an onclick handler set up, so just set up a breakpoint on line 504 (photo below) and click anywhere on the map to run the GP service.

[image: Debug screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the service is returning web mercator northings and eastings ([`wkid:3857`](http://epsg.io/3857) / [`102100`](http://epsg.io/102100)) not raw wgs84 lat/lon coordinates ([`wkid:4326`](http://epsg.io/4326)). you can get your GP service to return lat/long coordinates by supplying `4326` as the 'Output Spatial Reference' in the UI.

[../GPServer/FindSitesAcre_P/submitJob](http://argis.ualr-iea.org/arcgis/rest/services/geoServices/FindSitesAcre2/GPServer/FindSitesAcre_P/submitJob)

i snooped the web traffic when the actual request is made and it appears that the corresponding parameter name defined for your service is actually `env:outSR`. i've never seen one with a colon in it before, but there's a first time for everything i guess.

```
gpTask.setParam('env:outSR', 4326);
```

Comment: Awesome to see markers, getting closer, this works the first time, subsequent runs produce a 400 error `"The coordinates or measures are out of bounds."` . When I stopped the service and restarted it, it worked again the first time, when I restarted the service again and commented out the "env:outSR" line, it works everytime, but of course no markers on the leaflet side. Is the "env:outSR" an environment variable that the server holds on to once changed?  Is there a best practice I should be following? Thanks

Comment: So I changed my map and all layers to `wkid:4326`, ran and republished my model and it works consistently now, You definitely got me on the right track, appreciate the help!